# Create web server without specify in router settings

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have a local network with a virgin router. All my pcs are assigned dhcp addresses from routers dhcp server.
On one of my pcs I have Iis installed.
As I understand it to serve web pages from this iis to a remote browser I would have to know my wan ip and I would have to set a forwarding 'rule' in my server. Is there a way to bypass the router setting and have my iis listen out to external calls?
I am using c# and asp.net for this. 
My intent is to automatically configure this server for my users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the external traffic will have to go through the router.  You can however disable DCHP for a specific machine and assign it a static LAN IP  (dhcp won't work if it changes).

You'll need to set up a forwarding port on the external router.  For example, anything coming in on port 80 would forward to port 80 on iis.  The router will also need a public IP (or anther router that forwards to it with a public IP).

It's worth noting, if you are opening this up to the interwebs, it's a huge security risk.  Make sure the machine is patched  :)

Comment: Thanks for replying. My need is not to have any router settings and/ or port forwarding. It seems my suspicions were correct in that it cannot be done. I would have thought I would not need port warding as I would be using port 80 though?

Comment: Patched absolutely. I want to display images from my local PC in a web page without uploading to my server.  The user would login to view it.

Comment: It depends on the router.  Most I've seen will block all external traffic by default, until you add a rule to allow it.  Once you connect this to the web, you'll get lots of bots constantly probing for OS security holes... so they turn this off.

Comment: It does make sense to do so

Comment: DVR is pulling content in, into your network.  Two-way communication is allowed if it's initiated from inside the network.  But if someone pulls somethign from your server, you'd have to explicitly grant that.  Someone outside can't initiate the connection (by default).  Usually there's a web interface on a router that lets you set up a route.

Comment: So there must be a way to code this route don't you think without regard to the type of router being used?

Comment: So what if I initiated a 'connection' from a page on my local iis to my server iis - perhaps in the manner of signalR?

Comment: If they run a webservice, for example, you could connect to that service remotely and push an image to it.   Also, there are usually programitic ways to connect to a router an manipulate the configuration (add/drop routes).  But allowing someone to connect to your machine is almost always blocked by default (or should be).

Comment: Well at the moment that is what I do: call a web service to push images but the fps can slow down so when I looked at a dvr it uses it's own web server but they are a pain for the user to setup hence my dilemma

Comment: I push image from client to server to be able to access remotely is what I meant to say

Comment: If you can set up something like `rsync`, it's very efficient for pushing content to a remote system.   It will only send the bytes that change.   I would say bypassing the webservice and syncing the data between machines would be the best route overall.

Comment: Hmm interesting I never heard of that. Would it work for JPEGs I wonder? I shall have look - thanks

Comment: For binary data, it only sends files/bytes that change, between two directories.  I've used it to sync up 30GB+ of data in just a couple seconds.  :)  Though it's common more for linux development ... there may be a windows port or something on the windows side like it.

Comment: So limiting viewing pages on an iPhone! Are you suggesting syncing a image on local PC to an image on my server and then changing/updating the local image to initiate  updates/changes images on my server?

Comment: Sounds a great-alternative way to do things. I will need to do some investigating. Thanks

Comment: Yes, something like that.  If you have a directory of images locally, you can run rsync to push that directory to a remote server.  The first time it runs it takes a bit... then it's very fast to keep the two directories in sync.

Comment: Ah, that maybe an issue then as I want to stream images from my camera to my server 1 image at a time. Still u have explained the router stuff well and given me something to research so thanks :)